# Changing Text Binding on User Control fires text changed event but doesnt detect the new text

Tags: c#, textbox, textchanged

I have a custom WPF TextBox User Control. Im writing some content, but it always detects the same data that was preset on the XAML, new written text is not shown by doing textbox.Text get call.

```
public partial class SearchBox : UserControl
{
    public SearchBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox textBox && textBox.Tag.ToString() == textBox.Text)
            textBox.Clear();
    }
    private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox textBox && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
            textBox.Text = textBox.Tag.ToString();
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public event TextChangedEventHandler TextChanged;
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        TextChangedEventHandler h = TextChanged;
        if (h != null)
        {
            h(this, args);
        }
    }
}
```

How it needs to work:

```
<v:SearchBox x:Name="searchBox" TextChanged="searchBox_TextChanged" Text="Input a keyword to filter..." Tag="Input a keyword to filter..." HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

User writes on textbox "test" --> textbox.Text returns "Input a keyword to filter..."

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your `searchBox_TextChanged` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class inherits from `UserControl` and not `TextBox`.

Though you haven't shared your XAML for `SearchBox`, I assume you have a `TextBox` in it, which you are hoping to get the text from. Problem is, the property `SearchBox.Text` is different from `SearchBox.TextBox.Text`. As a result, even if you change the text in the `TextBox`, `SearchBox.Text` remains the same.

Solution: use `SearchBox.TextBox.Text` for your result.

Comment: This did the work, thanks so much. Do you have any idea to make it pretty so i can just do SearchBox.text to gather the textbox text?

Comment: To do that, change `SearchBox` to inherit from `TextBox` instead of `UserControl`. Then change the references in your code from `TextBox` to `SearchBox`. You will have to re-implement some of the events.